# Create the Pairing limitation on HC-05 sensor

Tags: arduino, bluetooth-lowenergy, hc-05

I have been trying to set the limit of pairing the Bluetooth device [HC-05](https://www.electronicscomp.com/hc-05-bluetooth-module-buy-in-india?gclid=Cj0KCQjwguDeBRDCARIsAGxuU8acsC5TqOCXGIDkSQ8E3BflIibMvtaRlQnnde4GX__5jzhwq_xDKn8aAuiIEALw_wcB)(interface by Arduino controller) with my smartphone.

I have tried making this solution work with AT command

```
AT+INQM=<Param>,<Param2>,<Param3>
Example: AT+INQM=1,9,48\r\n
```

But instead of converting AT commands using serial.h with embedded C, I am looking for any dedicated library which helps to work this kind solution in using Arduino.

Basically, with the help of Bluetooth device connect to Arduino Nano, I want to send the [altimeter sensor](https://store.ncd.io/product/ms5637-02ba03-barometric-pressure-sensor-with-24-bit-analog-to-digital-converter-i2c-mini-module/) data to my smartphone.

During the connection, HC-05 should be responding any one device at a time, if another smartphone tries to pair then the error will be shown.

Please share your advice on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there are some libraries in arduino but these are only meant for connection and pairing and low energy connections. We don't have any dedicated library from where we can control the mode of operation of HC05 or any bluetooth module. like bypassing or accessing GAP and GATT services of bluetooth. However there is a way to flash HC-05. But we can only use it for updating the firmware of this device. This [github repo](https://github.com/lorf/csr-spi-ftdi) is dedicated for this purpose . Hope  it helps you